# Make redux-persist to notify me when data are restored

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, persist

I have large amount of data that I'm storing in local storage using react persist. What I need is to know when persist data were restored in my reducer (when app is loading). I need to validate  data version and I need to generate lookup object (which redux-storage us unable to store,  probably because  because it has around 65405 records/fields).

Anyway I would like to know when react-persist is loading my data so I can work with them. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I guess you can use `useTransform` from redux-persist
Checkout the documentation here: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#transforms

Answer (score 0):

There are two special actions in `redux-persis`: `PERSIST` and `REHYDRATE`.

The `PERSIST` action has been dispatched and then with `REHYDRATE`, the saved object of the `store` will be load and injected into the current redux store. So, you can import them into your `reducer` functions and be aware of  **persisting** status.

You need to manipulate the data before re-hydrated them with persistor, but I recommend doing a simpler approach to handle this case.

For example, there is a `data` value (which is contain 65405 records):

```
case DATA_ARRIVED_SUCCESSFULLY:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: actin.payload
  }
```

Now, before persisting and before putting the payload on `data`, you can check and validate your data:

```
const sampleValidatorData = (myData) => {
  // do something with myData
}

case DATA_ARRIVED_SUCCESSFULLY:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: sampleValidatorData(actin.payload)
  }
```

Now, your saved data (with persistor) will be valid.